# Не уничтожать обьект при загрузке другой сцены в Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

Возможно ли передать значения из одного скрипта на одной сцене в другой скрипт на другой сцене в Unity? Мне нужно сделать начисление монет за убийства врагов в сцене боя, а потом прибавить полученные монеты в бою к общему количеству монет, которое отображается в другой сцене, в которой можно эти монеты потратить, грубо говоря в магазине.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно создать обьект который будет мигровать со сцены в другую сцену. И на этот скрипт нацепить уже клас который будет в себе сохранять все данные нужные, например количество монет.
Или же не выгружать твоего персонажа и что бы скрипт висел на нем.

То есть нужно смотреть в сторону Object.DontDestroyOnLoad

```
DontDestroyOnLoad(this.gameObject);
```

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html

Comment: Такс, спасибо большое, похоже, это и есть решение, очень выручили