# Анимированная смены сцены

Tags: c#, unity3d, scene-builder

Я хочу, чтобы при смене сцены(выходе в меню), воспроизводилась анимация. Я думал, что можно сделать скриншот состояния нынешней сцены, а затем сделать анимацию свайпа. Но у меня ничего не вышло, можете пожалуйста помочь?

Comment: Вы хотите сделать что-то на подобие загрузочного экрана?

Comment: не совсем, я пишу игру в жанре визуальной новеллы, и нуждаюсь в красивом переходе между уровнями(сценами)

Comment: Из вопроса в вопрос один и тот же совет - не изобретать велосипед, а использовать готовый движок для визуальных новелл. Там уже сразу есть весь функционал, который может понадобиться для визуальных новелл, в том числе и подобные переходы. Я серьезно говорю, что проще плюнуть на уже сделанную работу и перейти на другой движок, чем дописывать то что есть. При чем будет легче как тебе, так и телефонам пользователей с конечным продуктом.

Comment: Какие люди)))) Я посмотрел некоторые гайды по ренпаю, по вашему совету. И пока переход планировать не собираюсь по нескольким причинам: 1) Ренпай имеет некоторые ограничения. А я хочу прям капец как все наворотить. 2) Я позиционирую юньку - как универсальный инструмент, а новелла - только начало, чисто для опыта и набития некоторых шишек. Потом хочу написать некоторый платформер, а все эти шишки мне и помогут)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. сделать скриншот
2. разместить на сцене канвас на который разместить картинку со скриншотом
3. асинхронно загрузить новый уровень при этом не выгружая канвас ([Не уничтожать обьект при загрузке другой сцены в Unity](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1131214/%d0%9e%d0%b1%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b4%d1%83-%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bf%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%b2-unity-c/1131245#1131245) )
4. по окончанию загрузки уровня запустить анимацию которая отодвигает изображение вбок
5. убить канвас